# Julia-Lang how to solve tridiagonal system

Tags: julia, matrix-factorization

I'm new at Julia-Lang and I'm trying to solve a symmetric tridiagonal system in Julia several times, so I, assemble my matrix as

```
SymTridiagonal( e ,ones(L-4) )
```

what changes in my system is the right-hand side. So I tried to use Chris Rackauckas solution on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486697/solve-a-particular-linear-system-efficiently-in-julia), which I quote:

> Just do X=lufact(X) and then X\b

The thing is that when I do that I get

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching lufact!(::SymTridiagonal{Float64})

lufact!(!Matched::Union{Base.ReshapedArray{T<:Union{Complex{Float32}, Complex{Float64}, Float32, Float64},2,A,MI}
```

So my question is: What is the right way to make the imput to lufact! function

Comment: use `lufact!(Tridiagonal(X))`. Apparently, there is no automatic fallback from symmetric to non-symmetric tridiagonal matrices.

Comment: or perhaps more explicitly: `X = lufact(Tridiagonal(X))` and then `X\b`

Comment: I thought tridiagonal systems can be solved in linear time already. Why is a factorization needed?

Answer (score 1):

The default factorization for `SymTridiagonal` matrices is LDLt (obtained from `ldltfact`), instead of LU (obtained from `lufact`). If you just want to solve the system `Ax=b` where `A` is a `SymTridiagonal` it is enough to do

```
x = A\b
```

and julia will dispatch to `ldltfact` to solve the problem. If you want to be explicit about it (or want to use the factorization for something else) you can use

```
F = ldltfact(A) # or F = factorize(A) which will also return LDLt
x = F\b
```

If specifically need an LU-factorization you can use

```
F = lufact(Tridiagonal(A))
```

as pointed out in the comments, but it is more efficient to use `ldltfact` in this case.